# transaction logging in sql

Tags: sql

What type of transaction logging does ANSI compliant Sql use?

Comment: The ANSI SQL standard does not specify anything about how transactions are _implemented_ only how they should _work_.  Transaction logging is a technical aspect of the _implementation_ and is not covered by the SQL standard. If a DBMS can support full ACID compliance and all properties required by the SQL standard without "transaction logging" then it's still ANSI compliant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Transaction Logging
>
> ANSI-compliant databases run with unbuffered transaction logging. In
>   an ANSI-compliant database, you cannot change the logging mode to
>   buffered logging, and you cannot turn logging off.
>
> For more information, see the description of the CREATE DATABASE
>   statement in the IBM Informix: Guide to SQL Syntax.

Source : http://jgharris.com/informix-version-10/ddi/ddi32.htm